# Insert array items on conditions and calculate its sum

Tags: android

```
        "PaymentMode": "Cash",
        "Amount": 1000,
        "PaymentReferenceNumber": "",

      },
      {

        "PaymentMode": "CcAve",
        "Amount": 500,
        "PaymentReferenceNumber": "",

      },

      {

        "PaymentMode": "cash",
        "Amount": 0,
        "PaymentReferenceNumber": "IN0001-113",

      },
      {

        "PaymentMode": "Credited",
        "Amount": 500,
        "PaymentReferenceNumber": "IN0001-114",

      }
```

This is how i get my json response. What i need to do is that, those 'amount' value whose corresponding payment reference number is empty or null needs to be added.This is what i have done

```
public int getTotalPayments() {
    int total = 0;
    for(OrderPayment payment : orderPayments) {
        if(payment.getPaymentReferencenumber().isEmpty()||payment.getPaymentReferencenumber().equals("NULL")){
          total += payment.getAmount();
       }
    }

    return total;
}
```

But I am getting wrong. Can anyone help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am getting a wrong value for sum. it takes in all the values with and without refernce number@Rohit5k2

Answer (score 0):

Your Condition is wrong . In am assuming you are checking for a blank Reffrence number here.
So it should be as :-

```
public int getTotalPayments() {
    int total = 0;
    for(OrderPayment payment : orderPayments) {
        if (isEmpty(payment.getPaymentReferencenumber())) {
            total += payment.getAmount();
        }
    }
    return total;
}

private boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str))
        return true;
    return str.toLowerCase().equals("null");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but now i am getting '0' as the sum,again a wrong value@ADM

Comment: when i debug, i get reference number as "", but it has value.. i cannot find out the reason for it@ADM

Comment: It should work if the data you provided is inside `orderPayments` .. How are you calling `getTotalPayments` ? Add code ..

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logic, you say you're getting the sum of:

- References that are empty
  OR
- References that are NOT "NULL"

And most of the stuff is not null.

To answer your question, just remove the `!`:

```
        if(payment.getPaymentReferencenumber().isEmpty()||payment.getPaymentReferencenumber().equals("NULL")){
```

Which is 
 - References that are empty
OR
 - References that are "NULL"